# Add Logo/Picture to Navbar in javascript file (beginner)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

first time programmer here. I basically just followed a big and great instruction to build an easy website and conducted little changes.

But I really want to add a nice logo to my simple navbar. I researched a lot and tried different solutions, but my knowledge is not sufficient to apply it to my project.

I have this .js file with the Navbar. Can I add a small logo next to the title here (preferably on the left of the title? Or do I need to do this somewhere else in my project? I can add the picture file in the same folder as the js. file, if this makes the inserting easier. The file is called "img.png".

This is the code:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter> 
      <div className="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
        <header>
          <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg">
            <Container>
              <Navbar.Brand>Project XXX</Navbar.Brand>
              <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                  <Nav className="me-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
                    <a href="/admin" className="nav-link" target="_blank">
                    VacationBOT
                    </a>
                  </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
              </Navbar.Toggle>
            </Container>
          </Navbar>
        </header>
        <main>
          <Container className="mt-3">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/admin" element={<AdminPage />}></Route>
              <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
            </Routes>
          </Container>
        </main>
        <footer className="mt-auto">
          <div className="text-center">Footer XXX</div>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    
  );
}
```

I checked many other questions on stackoverflow and added different code to my code, but I couldn't manage to make it work.

Many other stackoverflow threads also added some code to some .html files. But my only html-files are some index.html.

This is more or less the website that I duplicated: https://github.com/basir/support-desk-app
The .js I am talking about is the App.js in the frontend/src folder.

Sorry for this beginner question. Thank you very much in advance! If you need more code or information, let me know. I will try my best to provide this info :).

Comment: It looks like you are using react-bootstrap. Look at the documentation on the Navbar Brand. Specifically look at the 3rd and 4th example in the Brand example. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/docs/components/navbar#brand

Comment: And what if you just add the logo to the navbar brand element? `<Navbar.Brand><img src={myImage}></Navbar.Brand>`. And `import myImage from "logo.png".`

Comment: If you are a complete beginner I would suggest not using a CSS library but simply use `flex` to put your navbar items next to each other. `<nav><div>logo here</div><div>nav item here</div></nav>` and then in css: `nav {display:flex}`.

Comment: @Kokodoko Thank you very much for your reply! It works! I could put it in the navbar brand element. I just got an error, because I had to close the <img>, but then it worked fine. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @StuartNichols I could solve it, thank you very much for your reply :) This is a very useful documentation.